# Java: Compare dates on same timezone

Tags: java, date, timezone

Given:

```
SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat ("yy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
sd.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Date d = sd.parse("a date similar to now on local computer");
```

if I compare `d.getTime()` with `new Date().getTime()`, the values are different with more than one hour. Why?

Comment: Because they aren't the same timezone. One is GMT, the other isn't. Try `sd.format(new Date())`

Comment: how can I make them the same timezone, without altering new Date().getTime()?

Comment: Change your system timezone to GMT?

Comment: if I am not setting the timezone, I still get a discrepancy of more than one hour

Comment: Are you checking in the afternoon? Your SimpleDateFormat isn't using 24hr hour values and isn't showing AM/PM. So the afternoon will look exactly like the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your timezones. You are comparing a time that isn't in GMT.

Answer (score 1):

You're explicitly setting your `SimpleDateFormat` to parse in GMT, which means that when you parse the  current clock time, you're getting the moment of time when that time occurred, in the GMT time zone.  If you're not in the GMT time zone, that won't be "now".

Comment: if I am not setting the timezone, I still get a discrepancy of more than one hour

Comment: Then give us more details.  What is your system time zone?  What time are you actually passing to `sd.parse`?  And what is the actual time when  you're doing it?

Answer (score 1):

`Date` objects don't know anything about timezones - there is no explicit timezone information in a `Date` object. A `Date` object represents an "absolute" moment in time (it's a timestamp). This means you should not think of a `Date` object as "a date in a certain timezone" - it has no timezone.

Suppose that from some source you get a `String` that contains a date and time, without an explicit timezone mentioned in it, for example: `2014-12-16 17:30:48.382`. Suppose that you know that this date and time is in the GMT timezone.

You could then parse it to a `Date` object with an appropriate `SimpleDateFormat` object:

```
DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

// Set the timezone of the SimpleDateFormat to GMT, because you know the string
// should be interpreted as GMT
fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

// Parse the String into a Date object
Date dateTime = fmt.parse("2014-12-16 17:30:48.382");

// Date object which is set to "now"
Date now = new Date();

// Compare it to "now"
if (dateTime.before(now)) {
    System.out.println("The specified date is in the past");
} else if (dateTime.after(now)) {
    System.out.println("The specified date is in the future");
} else {
    System.out.println("The specified date is now");
}
```

If you want to print the date in a certain timezone, then do so by formatting it with a `SimpleDateFormat` set to the appropriate timezone.

```
DateFormat outfmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z");
outfmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EDT"));

// Will print dateTime in the EDT timezone
System.out.println(outfmt.format(dateTime));
```